# Sorting Across Distributed Spinx Index via SphinxSE

Tags: sorting, sphinx

We currently have a Sphinx 2.2.3beta install on one server and Sphinx 2.0.4 on another. Both have their own build of two indexes on them, each with a distributed index over these two local indices (ie. each server has 'index1' and 'index2', and each has 'index_dist' being a distributed index over 'index1' and 'index2').

When using SphinxSE to query against the distributed index and sorting against a given attribute, we are finding that the results from the 2.2.3beta seem to be given as the sorted results from the first local index followed by the sorted results from the second index.

When performing the same query against the distributed index on the 2.0.4 server, the results are completely sorted (as in, the results from the first local index, combined with the results from the second local index, and then sorted).

This is not an issue when performing the query via SphinxQL, but it is a problem if we make the query via either the PHP Sphinx API or via SphinxSE.

Does anyone have any thoughts / hints / comments around this please?

Comment: same issue here... rolling back to 2.0.4 :(

Comment: @anonymous-one: I had forgotten about this question until your comment. I posted a bug with Sphinx and got a reply with a workaround (for now). It's at http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this issue at http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2023 . It's since been resolved but in the mean time, you can either:

- download the latest code, rebuild SphinxSE and restart mysqld; or
- add select=* to your SphinxSE query

The second option seemed to work for us.